# Compiler not allowing to define a compiler-generated constructor

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define the constructor that compiler generates automatically and resulted in an compilation error. Here is my code:

```
class myclass
 {
   public:
       void Test_Func()
       {}
 };
myclass::myclass()
{
}
```

Is compiler doing anything in addition for a simple class like above. Here is the error that I got in MSVC compiler:

```
"error C2600: 'myclass::myclass' : cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The synthesised constructor is both declared and defined. You may not define it yourself.

You'll have to declare your own constructor in order to provide an implementation.

`[special]` (2003 wording, 12/1) says:

> The default constructor (12.1), copy
>   constructor and copy assignment
>   operator (12.8), and destructor (12.4)
>   are special member functions. The
>   implementation will implicitly declare
>   these member functions for a class
>   type when the program does not
>   explicitly declare them, except as
>   noted in 12.1. **The implementation will
>   implicitly define them if they are
>   used**, as specified in 12.1, 12.4 and
>   12.8. **Programs shall not define implicitly-declared special member
>   functions.**

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot define a user-generated default constructor if it hasn't been declared. The compiler already defines it, so you have defined multiple default constructors. You *must* declare a default constructor if you wish to define one- just like any other function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
class myclass { public: myclass(); void Test_Func() {} }; myclass::myclass() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to define the function, it needs to be included in the class declaration, like so:

```
class myclass { public: myclass(); void Test_Func() {} }; myclass::myclass() { }
```